# ggplot: Overlaying density curves on a histogram when also grouping by a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a histogram with density on the y-axis and with the density curve overlaid on top. This works fine if I don't group the data by another factor. However, when I add in a fill, the output is not what I expected.

```
noFill = ggplot(movies, aes(x=rating, weight=votes/sum(votes)))+ 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), binwidth = 1) + 
  geom_density(alpha = .1, fill="blue")
noFill
```

Adding in a fill:

```
filled = ggplot(movies, aes(x=rating, fill = mpaa,
                            weight=votes/sum(votes)))+ 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), 
                 position = "identity", alpha = .6, 
                 binwidth = 1) +
  geom_density(alpha = .3)
filled
```

These are the plots I get:

[image]

[image]

I also get the following warnings from the 'filled' code:

```
Warning messages:
1: In density.default(data$x, adjust = adjust, kernel = kernel, weight = data$weight,  :
  sum(weights) != 1  -- will not get true density
2: In density.default(data$x, adjust = adjust, kernel = kernel, weight = data$weight,  :
  sum(weights) != 1  -- will not get true density
3: In density.default(data$x, adjust = adjust, kernel = kernel, weight = data$weight,  :
  sum(weights) != 1  -- will not get true density
4: In density.default(data$x, adjust = adjust, kernel = kernel, weight = data$weight,  :
  sum(weights) != 1  -- will not get true density
5: In density.default(data$x, adjust = adjust, kernel = kernel, weight = data$weight,  :
  sum(weights) != 1  -- will not get true density
```

Based on the warnings and the way the graph looks, I suspect that there's an issue with the weights of the entire dataset being applied to each fill group instead of calculating the weights per group. I'm sure the current behavior is desirable in many circumstances, but I'm looking to make the density curves follow the histogram. Can I induce this behavior without having to calculate the stats manually?

EDIT:
Here is a hack that works to further illustrate what I want. In this code I simply add each group density curve as a separate layer and pass in a df containing only that groups data. This obviously forces the density calculations to be per group instead of aggregated over all data.

```
filled = ggplot(movies, aes(x=rating, fill = mpaa,
                            weight=votes/sum(votes)))+ 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), 
                 position = "identity", alpha = .6, 
                 binwidth = 1)
for (grp in rev(levels(movies$mpaa))) {
  df = movies %>% filter(mpaa == grp)
  layer = geom_density(data = df, alpha = .3)
  filled = filled + layer
}
filled
```

The "rev" in the for loop is just so NC-17 gets plotted last so you can see more clearly.

Here's the plot (again I do not have privileges to post images yet):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yf13n.jpg

Also, in case it's relevant, in the end I will be taking out the histograms entirely. I just want densities per group. So if there is a method to do this without the histogram I would be happy as well.

Comment: What is your desired output? you can add `position="stack"` to your `geom_density` call and that looks like what you desired

Comment: This doesn't quite do it. If you do that, notice that you still pretty much do not see the NC-17 density curve because there are so few NC-17 movies. I want a density curve that very clearly follows the NC-17 histogram (and similar for others).

Comment: gotcha, try adding `aes(y = (..scaled..)/2.5)` to the geom_density call. `..scaled..` will scale them all to have a max of 1, the /2.5 is a rough correction to match the histograms

Comment: Interesting! I did not know about ..scaled..  Thanks for the tip. If you're interested, you might also check out the hack I edited in the OP. Though I'm still interested if it's possible to just force ggplot to calculate statistics per group in geom_density like it seems to do in geom_histogram.